# Chrome font rendering

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

Faced with incorrect font rendering in chrome.

The screenshot shows that the first item in the list has a different color:
[image]

But all items in list have the same css properties:
[image]

Approximation looks like this:
[image]

For example, IE 11 does not have that problem:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[backface-visibility: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) will help